# Android SSL certificate issue

Tags: android, ssl, httprequest

I've used:

```
sudo openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out /path/to/cert.pem -keyout /path/to/cert.pem
```

to create a certificate and

```
keytool -importcert -v -trustcacerts -file "cert.pem" -alias ca -keystore "mySrvTruststore.bks" -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath "bcprov-jdk16-145.jar" -storetype BKS -storepass pass
```

using  bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.46, to create a bkr keystore. I've imported the bkr keystore in my android app in /res/raw/...  .

My android code:

```
protected org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory createAdditionalCertsSSLSocketFactory() {
        try {
            final KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");

            // the bks file we generated above
            final InputStream in = RestaurantHanovra.getAppResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mysrvtruststore);  
            try {
                // don't forget to put the password used above in strings.xml/mystore_password
                ks.load(in, "pass".toCharArray());
            } finally {
                in.close(); 
            }

            return new MySSLSocketFactory(ks);

        } catch( Exception e ) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

I'm getting this error when i try to execute http requests:

```
08-17 16:18:19.778: W/System.err(16906): javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x5168b318: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
08-17 16:18:19.778: W/System.err(16906): error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:766 0x4172bb5a:0x00000000)
08-17 16:18:19.778: W/System.err(16906):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:420)
08-17 16:18:19.783: W/System.err(16906):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.<init>(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:636)
08-17 16:18:19.783: W/System.err(16906):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.getInputStream(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:607)
08-17 16:18:19.783: W/System.err(16906):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.<init>(SocketInputBuffer.java:70)
08-17 16:18:19.783: W/System.err(16906):    at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.createSessionInputBuffer(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:83)
08-17 16:18:19.788: W/System.err(16906):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.createSessionInputBuffer(DefaultClientConnection.java:170)
08-17 16:18:19.788: W/System.err(16906):    at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.bind(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:106)
08-17 16:18:19.788: W/System.err(16906):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.openCompleted(DefaultClientConnection.java:129)
08-17 16:18:19.788: W/System.err(16906):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:172)
08-17 16:18:19.788: W/System.err(16906):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
08-17 16:18:19.788: W/System.err(16906):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
08-17 16:18:19.788: W/System.err(16906):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
08-17 16:18:19.788: W/System.err(16906):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
08-17 16:18:19.793: W/System.err(16906):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
08-17 16:18:19.793: W/System.err(16906):    at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:76)
08-17 16:18:19.793: W/System.err(16906):    at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:95)
08-17 16:18:19.793: W/System.err(16906):    at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:57)
08-17 16:18:19.793: W/System.err(16906):    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
08-17 16:18:19.798: W/System.err(16906):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
08-17 16:18:19.798: W/System.err(16906):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
08-17 16:18:19.798: W/System.err(16906):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
08-17 16:18:19.798: W/System.err(16906):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-17 16:18:19.798: W/System.err(16906): Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x5168b318: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
08-17 16:18:19.798: W/System.err(16906): error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:766 0x4172bb5a:0x00000000)
08-17 16:18:19.803: W/System.err(16906):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
08-17 16:18:19.808: W/System.err(16906):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:378)
08-17 16:18:19.808: W/System.err(16906):    ... 21 more
```

although i've checked my webservices in the browser, and everything works fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question, the problem was that I was sending requests on 8080 instead if 8443. That's what `"SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol "` indicated.

Use this method if you need it.